# VB.NET panel can't display correctly inside of groupbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to locate panel bring to front of groupbox(scale setting panel), but it doesn't work. (see attached picture)[image]
Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the panel is bigger than the GroupBox and you want it to be shown, then it can't be a part of the GroupBox control's collection.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: The designer for the Panel class will fight you tooth and nail, trying to make the groupbox a child of the panel.  You'll have to fight back with View > Other Windows > Document Outline.

Comment: Try sending the temperature setting panel to the back

Comment: Drag the panel onto the gray area (the form?). Now it can be brought to the front (in front of the scale and temperature groupboxes). Now you can resize the panel to be on top of the groupboxes. This being said, I really don't like this design